# when importing a second python code, it cannot see other functions

Tags: function, python-3.x, methods, python-import

I have python program that imports a other python programs.  The imported programs cannot see other functions.  How can I make this work?  Codes looks like this:

#### prog1.py

```
def getrate:
    code lines...
    return rate

i = 0
for col in myforms:
   if myforms[i] == '911'
      import prog2
      prog2.calc(revenue)
   elseif myforms[i] = 'SALES'
      import prog3
      prog3.calc(revenue)
   elseif  .....
      ....
      ....
   i+=1
```

#### prog2.py

```
def calc(sales):
    rate = getrate()
    tax = sales * rate
    return tax
```

When prog2.calc() is executed, it cannot call getrate().  I'm a novice and I'm grateful to any help assistance you can provide.  TIA

Answer (score 0):

In `prog2` you need to do this:

```
import prog1
prog1.getrate()
```

Comment: PROG1 is actually my main program and in it I am importing PROG2 which calls a function in PROG1.  If I add that line in PROG2 and imports PROG1, won't that create some sort of a cyclic error?

Comment: @glim: Oh.  You can't (or shouldn't) really be doing that then.  A "main program" in Python should not define functions to be used elsewhere.  Move your `getrate()` function to a third file that both prog1 and prog2 can call.

Comment: That's probably what I need to do.  Move all of my other functions to a different program that the other programs can keep on calling. Will give it a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you move the function `getrate()` to `prog2.py`?

Comment: I can but getrate() is actually has more codes than that (about 25 lines) and I have several other programs (like PROG3 - PROG60)  that needs it so I really want to keep it in the main program and just call it each time instead of adding it into the other programs.

Comment: In my working with Python, using a simple `import` statement will run the code from _prog1.py_ from the line `i=0` into the `for` loop and so on. I would suggest (to prevent that from happening) try importing the definition into _prog2.py_ like this: `from prog1 import getrate`